# CKEditor classes being stripped

Tags: class, ckeditor

I have a custom plugin that adds a link with a class attached. When I view this using the Source button it shows the class and looks as it should. However, when I go back to WYSYWIG view and then view the source again the class has been stripped out.

Any idea how to stop this happening?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Which version of CKEditor?

Comment: @PeterKrauss [**STOP**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2774358) [**THIS**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2774351). This is not what editing is for. If you have a comment to add to a question or answer, use the link labeled **add comment**.

Comment: Somebody voting the answer WITHOUT EDITED IT (!). Stop the friend-voting to  rob my offer of bounty.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Please stop making mess. It's not your question and if you have anything specific, what was not included in my answer (generic answer for generic question), ask your own question. Also, please read linked blog post because your comment under my answer doesn't make any sense. It's clear to me that you haven't read it.

Comment: @meagar,  my initial perception was "I am **under attack**!"... It is difficult to have another perception if you receive "voting attack" without any comment (!). Now I have a position of Reinmar. Please, both, accept my apologies.

Comment: @Reinamar, about "ask your own question", I was avoiding "to duplicate question", reusing an pre-existing question; I think this is what Stackoverflow community like to incentivate. Perhaps the discussion at your answer shows the best way (stay here or to create another question).

Answer (score 1):

Check [this blog post](http://ckeditor.com/blog/Integrating-Plugins-with-Advanced-Content-Filter).

In CKEditor 4.1 RC we've introduced ACF - Advanced Content Filter. You need to integrate your plugin with it, because otherwise special content created by it is stripped.

Answer (score 0):

For CKEditor4 and for simple `config.js` modification, disabling the "default filters": see [this new question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18386864/287948).

---

(copy)

At `config.js` you can add something like,

```
  CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent=true;
```

see "Advanced Content Filter" ([ACF](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.1-Released)) and [how to enable/disable it](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent).

Comment: That's correctly explained in the documentation and Reinmar already linked to it. So it seems that you wanted an answer before spending the time to understand the existing answer.

Comment: Yes, my bounty was to "not expend my time": I think is valid (and Stackoverflow have many examples) to request, by a bounty, a "more detailed" and "explicit code" for a solution. Now, after the commented "voting attack" I lost my time and my bounty.  I personaly dislike answers that show a link to "100 paragraphs discussion" as a solution that have 1 line of code.

Comment: When someone makes a basic and too broad question then it's obvious that the answer must be also broad and a link to the documentation seems better than suggesting to turn everything off. There are several other questions about the ACF system in CKEditor, and usually they provide more data in the question itself, so they might have more specific answers.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: As I wrote previously - this answer is not correct from plugin developer's point of view. It is only correct for integrations and this question was about a plugin. EOT.

Comment: @AfonsoML, I understand the "bounty question" is a increment to the question, and I supply my point in the "bounty text".  By other hand, I also not agree that the answer to the original question not need a line of code, see the [original link](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.1-Released) of Reinmar post: ZacWolf understand as me (!), and after Anna need to explain better.

Comment: @Reinmar, sorry, I not undertand your point, I solve me problem with a line of code in the `config.js`, and into the scope of this question. It is about CKEDITOR-X, and I only upgrade to CKEDITOR-4.